# How to use maven plugin in profile in settings.xml

Tags: java, maven, settings

I try to make a default profile which is stored in the `settings.xml` and can be called by `mvn clean install -Pmy-profile`. I can not put it in the local `pom.xml`.

My profile looks like this:

```
<profile>
  <id>check-release</id>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>enforce-no-snapshots</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <rules>
                <requireReleaseVersion>
                  <message>No Snapshots Allowed!</message>
                </requireReleaseVersion>
              </rules>
              <fail>true</fail>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</profile>
```

But I got:

```
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective settings
[WARNING] Unrecognised tag: 'build'
```

and the plugin seems not to do what I want. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should provide whole pom.xml. profile must be inside profiles tag.

Comment: Simple answer to this is: It is not possible to define plugins in settings in any way...

Comment: Why can't you put the profile in e.g. your parent pom?

Answer (score 0):

Following khmarbaise's comment see [Settings Reference – Profiles](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Profiles):

> The `profile` element in the `settings.xml` is a truncated version of the `pom.xml` `profile` element. It consists of the `activation`, `repositories`, `pluginRepositories` and `properties` elements. The `profile` elements only include these four elements [...]

Comment: So you can't configure a plugin in the settings.xml?

Comment: @mealesbia Apparently, yes.